# How to embed a terminal the desktop of Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: gnome-terminal

I tried the Compiz window rule. But it doesn't work for Ubuntu 15.10 since you can no longer customize the title of your gnome terminal.

Do you guys have any idea how to do it?

[image]

Comment: I am not getting what is exactly your goal...

Comment: The title is set in the General tab, I think.

Comment: You can no longer set the title in the preferences, but you can via escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it!

1.Download the Tilda.

2.Set up the Tilda to your preferred position.

3.In Compiz,  configure the Window Rules as follow.

[Image of window rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZWTJ.png)

4.Add a startup option

[Image of startup application settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2F7L.png)

5.You are done!!!